# Redirect from testing site to production site

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

So if a visitor is located at the testing site `http://testing.site.com/app/article/123qwag` how can I redirect him to the same article but in the main app's domain: `http://www.app.com/article/123qwag`

Except for me, which I will identify myself through a couple of ips (dynamic ones). Which is the best way to accomplish this, **php** or **.httacces**?

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

Note: I'm using **codeigniter framework**

it redirects me to `www.app.comindex.php`

**EDIT2**
Ok so here is some of my `.htaccess` (combined with: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess)

This `.htaccess` works great for me, thanks for your help with the redirection

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^app.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
#  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
#  RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=12.23.45.67
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.app.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# RewriteBase equivalent - Localhost
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/codeigniter-app/]

# RewriteBase equivalent - Development
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^testing.app.com$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/app/]

# RewriteBase equivalent - Development
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.app.com$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]

# Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php?/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: yes to all, but how the exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use mod_rewrite, because it's handled directly in the server, thus faster.

**1. mod_rewrite solution**

You can use the following statements in your `.htaccess` to **redirect the user to www.app.com**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^testing.app.com$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=12.34.56.78
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=12.34.56.79
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://wwww.app.com$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Why do we use a 301 redirect here? Because otherwise Google may put your testing site into the index. See here for details: [Google and the 301 redirects](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633). This also checks your IP.

Please make sure that mod_rewrite is loaded. On many servers it is not activated by default.

**2. PHP Solution**

Using PHP would be possible. You need to make sure you route every through these statements, so you can include this in your main config file. It will be slow, but might be easier to deploy, depending on your hosting environment.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != "12.34.56.78" && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != "12.34.56.79") { // Your IPs
  header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
  header("Location: http://www.app.com/".str_replace("/^\/app/","",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
}
```

Comment: This does not take care of the /app-Folder in the testing-subdomain

Answer (score 3):

This one in the `.htaccess` of your testing subdomain should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /app
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=123\.45\.67\.[8-9]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.app.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This enables the `RewriteEngine`, sets it's base-path to the `/app`-folder and when the IP does not match `123.45.67.8/9` redirect everything in there with `HTTP 301` to `www.app.com` and appends the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your .htaccess uner DOCUMENT_ROOT

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^testing\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(app)/(article/(.*))/?$ http://www.$1.com/$2 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: I assume 123qwag was an example.